# Cannot see process.env.NODE_ENV within if-else

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

`console.log` shows `process.env.NODE_ENV production` and `I'm in if-statement` in console, why i cannot catch "else-statement"? With logic explanation i must be in else-statement.

```js
console.log('process.env.NODE_ENV', process.env.NODE_ENV)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  const webpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
  const webpack = require('webpack');
  const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
  app.use(webpackMiddleware(webpack(webpackConfig)));
  console.log('I\'m in if-statement');
} else {
  app.use(express.static('dist'));
  console.log('__dirname', __dirname);
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
  })
  console.log('I\'m in else-statement');
}
```

in console i type `set NODE_ENV=production && node server.js`

Comment: Are you sure that `process.env.NODE_ENV` doesn't have some trailing whitespace?

Comment: Thanks man, typed set NODE_ENV=production&& node server.js, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run`set NODE_ENV=production && node server.js`, `process.env.NODE_ENV` is set to `production`.

There is a `blank` after `production`. You can add `console.log('[' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ']');` in your file for test.